# An Objective-C class extension header - for what?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm familiar with Objective-C class extensions in class main implementation file, but curious for what the new Xcode 4.4 "An Objective-C class extension header" file template is intended for?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow and good first question !

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Class extensions must be implemented in the main `@implementation` block, but the declaration can be anywhere.

Extensions are used to add something to the class interface that you do not want to be public, and therefore cannot put in the public class declaration header.

Declaring the extension in the same file of the implementation, which you are familiar with, is used when the extension is only used by the class implementation itself.

Declaring the extension in a separate header, which is what the template is for, is useful when you develop a framework. The extension header will not be part of the set of public headers, but will be used internally by more than one implementation file of the framework.

You can think of it as *private to framework* instead of *private to class*.

Comment: +1 You can think of it as private to framework instead of private to class.

Comment: There was another primary motivation;  class extensions allow a class to advertise an @property as `readonly` and then *promote* it to `readwrite` internally.   This is explicitly disallowed with traditional categories.

Comment: Yes. The question was about the reason to put that _promotion_ into a header instead of doing it in the implementation file. Framework wide access and, as aleroot says, test case access are examples of why it may be useful.

Answer (score 9):

**Another reason** is that a Class Extension Header file is useful in the case you are **using Unit Test** to test your class, *putting class extension in a separate header file **allow you to import the the header containing private methods into the implementation of the class that needs those private methods and into the unit test file that you use to test the class*** ...

This is a very good addition(the opportunity to test private methods in the unit test)  to Objective-C in my opinion, it is a thing that you can't do at the moment with JUnit in Java .